# Natural or Human Sort order

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have been working on this on for months. I just cannot get the `natural` (True alpha-numeric) results.  I am shocked that I cannot get them as I have been able to in `RPG` since 1992 with `EBCDIC`.

I am looking for any solution in SQL, VBS or simple excel or access.  Here is the data I have:

```
299-8, 
3410L-87, 
3410L-88, 
420-A20, 
420-A21, 
420A-40, 
4357-3, 
AN3H10A, 
K117GM-8, 
K129-1, 
K129-15, 
K271B-200L, 
K271B-38L, 
K271D-200EL, 
KD1051, 
KD1062, 
KD1092, 
KD1108, 
KD1108, 
M8000-3, 
MS24665-1, 
SK271B-200L, 
SAYA4008
```

The order I am looking for is the true alpha-numeric order as below:

```
AN3H10A, 
KD1051, 
KD1062, 
KD1092, 
KD1108, 
KD1108, 
K117GM-8, 
K129-1, 
K129-15, 
MS24665-1,
M8000-3, 
SAYA4008, 
SK271B-200L
```

The inventory is 7800 records so I have had some problems with processing power as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Jeff

Comment: How is numbers-after-letters more natural than the other way around?

Comment: True alpha-numeric weights letters first in each column of the alpha-numeric string.  It came from bin cards then flat files later.  Fixed field widths caused a sort issue because they were not sorted by position of each character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In native Excel, you can add multiple sorting columns to return the ASCII code for each character, but if the character is a number, then add a large number to the code (e.g 1000).

Then sort on each of the helper columns, including the first column in the table, but not in the sort.

The formula:

```
=IFERROR(CODE(MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1))+AND(CODE(MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1))>=48,CODE(MID($A1,COLUMNS($A:A),1))<=57)*1000,"")
```

The Sort dialog:

[image]

The results:

[image]

You can implement a similar algorithm using VBA, and probably SQL also.  I dunno about VBS or Access.

Comment: I like the results of this method.  I am just missing some basics as to how to create the ASCII sort.  Any chance of a bit of step by step to create your result?

Comment: @Jeff What don't you understand?  How have you tried to implement this? Did you enter the formula anyplace? What were the results?

Comment: I implemented the formula in B1.  I understand what your thought process is to column each character to give it an ASCii order (i think).

Comment: @Jeff Just select B1 and fill down. Then select B1:Bn and fill right. Then look at the screenshot for sorting on each column.

Comment: B1:Bn!!! I know the deeper stuff but never even thought of sideways.  That worked great but after sorting on each column, column a still remained out of order.  I am not sure how you got it to re-sort.

Comment: I got it.  Missed selecting column A.  Thank you very much!!!!  I have been working on this for a few years on and off.  It would be awesome if someone could come up with an SQL statement but no luck so far.

Comment: @Jeff Glad you've got it figured out.  If the solution is working for you, I would appreciate it if you could mark my response as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try using format for left padding the string in order by

```
select column
from my_table 
order by  Format(column, "0000000000")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a sorting column:

```
, iif (left(fieldname, 1) between '0' and '9', 1, 0) sortField
etc
order by sortField, FieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your data in column "A". If you put this formula in column "B" `=IFERROR(IF(LEFT(A1,1)+1>0,"ZZZZZZZ     "&A1,A1),A1)`, it will automatically add Z in front of all numerical values, so that they will naturally appear after all alphabetical values when you sort A-Z. later you can find&replace that funny ZZZZZZ string...

Answer (score 0):

There a number of approaches, but likely the least amount of work is to build two columns that split out the delimiter (-) in this case.

You then “pad” the results (spaces, or 0) right justified, and then sort on the two columns.

So in the query builder we have this:

```
SELECT Field1, 
Format(
Mid(field1,1,IIf(InStr(field1,"-")=0,50,InStr(field1,"-")-1)),
">@@@@@@@@@@") AS Expr1,
Format(
Mid(field1,IIf(InStr(field1,"-")=0,99,InStr(field1,"-")+1)),
">@@@@@@@@@@") AS Expr2
FROM Data
```

When we run the above raw query we get this:

[image]

So now in the query builder, simply sort on the first derived column, and then sort on the 2nd derived column.

Eg this:

[image]

Run the query, and we get this result:

[image]

Edit:

Looking at you desired results, it looks like above sort is wrong. We have to RIGHT just and pad with 0’s.

So this 2nd try:

```
SELECT Field1, 
Left(Mid(field1,1,IIf(InStr(field1,"-")=0,30,InStr(field1,"-")-1)) 
& String(30,"0"),30) AS Expr1, 
Left(Mid(field1,IIf(InStr(field1,"-")=0,99,InStr(field1,"-")+1)) 
& String(30,"0"),30) AS Expr2
FROM Data
```

The results are thus this:

[image]

Given your small table size, then the above query should perform quite well.