# Sort Excel in Natural Order

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a large excel file containing a bunch of filenames (1000+). Now I want to sort the filenames inside the excel as they appear in the file system, which I discovered is using something called "Natural Sorting Order" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order). Any idea how?

The reason I need to do this is that I need to look through the files in the system one-by-one and add labels to the excel file. So it would be good to have the two in the same order.

Here is a snippet of the original excel filenames in A-Z order:

12132019015ecd11-5279-4068-9e56-679da3c269ea 
1213201901969230-a689-45aa-9c91-6fb19d463d6f 
1213201901c3bc1c-b482-4cb0-9d6a-1b03855b9a8e 
12132019022284b0-b2ef-4f2c-8684-39d65ef5ffdb 
121320190223f0e2-18e6-44a2-bb73-de511fa0d458 
...

But the file system (Mac OS and Ubuntu) sort the files like this:

12132019a1bb79a3-bd7f-4ec1-b1e6-3baa506abe68 
12132019a1c90a84-3acf-4fb5-8cd5-58ecc9f32d5c 
12132019a1ebd33c-3430-40fa-bd39-d590852758ac 
12132019a2e1a338-f82c-470d-b89c-fd3770f63fb4 
12132019a2eb1cc7-b51e-484a-979e-b45a3c583024 
...

Comment: maybe post what you have vs what you want? Also, here is another post on SO about sorting in natural order. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180955/natural-or-human-sort-order

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation but, unfortunately, it is not correct. In that algorithm, 12132019aaa74e1f-2f7a-4902-81cf-10e87b3db0be will rank before 12132019a1bb79a3-bd7f-4ec1-b1e6-3baa506abe68, which is not the case in the file system.

Comment: Put it in B1 and then just drag it to the right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Natural or Human Sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180955/natural-or-human-sort-order)

Comment: This was the same link as the first one, and I don't believe the answer is correct.

Comment: The issue with the scheme in the linked solution vs your problem is that the hyphen is included in the sort in the linked solution. I believe in your requirements the string has to be split by the hyphen, and each substring manipulated so it will sort properly.  If that is the case, it would be easier to do this in Power Query or VBA.